# Access 2007 conditional format when other control selected

Tags: formatting, ms-access-2007, conditional-statements

I'm not sure if this is the place to ask about this but I'm pulling my hair out here.

I'm trying to change the backcolor on a textbox (actually a few) when a combobox is selected.  I can do it with VBA but I really want to use the conditional formatting.  It would make life very simple.  It's a large form.  Lots of controls and this is for hilighting them when selected.  This is one of a group that need to be hilighted when the combobox is selected.

If this isn't the place to ask, please tell me.  If not, please help me!! I can't find anything that works.  I've been searching for hours.

My understanding is that if the expression is true then it will apply the formatting.

I've tried:

```
`ActiveControl = [cboVehTwo]`

`[cboVehTwo].ongotfocus = "True"`
```

And a whole ton of derivatives.  Referring to the form, etc...

Any help with the syntax would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA deals with events, such as yours:  a control getting focus or receiving a click.

Conditional formatting evaluates data to determine format issues.

So you need to use VBA.  About "making life very simple" -- use VBA.  Conditional formatting is a huge chore to maintain, even if it were appropriate for your case.  VBA is comparatively easy to maintain.

Comment: the problem I'm having is that I've got multiple situations on this form where I have a comobobox where a name is chosen.  The address, phone number, driver's licence number, etc are populated in txtboxes based on what name is chosen.  I had it where the other boxes weren't highlighted but the users couldn't figure out that if there was information missing in a field they couldn't enter it.  I'm sick of having to explain it.  Part of the solution is highlighting.I want to highlight them all when the combobox is selected.  The problem is I'm going to have to have code for each combobox.

Comment: In VBA I use:  `Me.txtVehTwoOwn_Add_Ln_1.BackColor = Me.cboVehTwoOwn_Name.BackColor` to perform the highlight for one txtbox.  I'd like to use a variable instead of the "VehTwoOwn" because the rest of the statement would be used repeatedly throughout.  It just seems to make more sense to use conditional formatting for each textbox in the group to highlight based on whether or not the comobobox is selected.

Comment: If you have a suggestion about how to incorporate the variable into the previous statement I'd love to hear it.  I've tried everyway I can think of and can't get it to work.  And I can't figure out a statement that works in the conditional formatting section.  I've been working on this an embarrassing amount of time and just want to move on.

Comment: I do appreciate that you've replied tho.  I can't believe that you're the only one.  This is just a syntax thing... you'd think it wouldn't take over 2 days for someone to suggest something...

Comment: The wait time you experienced is VERY unusual at SO, I can't explain that.  Thanks for describing the underlying issue.  I feel certain the best solution is to design the form so it communicates better.  I have some ideas, but due to schedule I won't get those posted for another five hours (sorry).

Comment: My advice: solve this with simple form design.  (A) Declare a logical group:  put a rectangle around the combo box and its dependent fields.  (B) Non-editable fields can have a transparent background, edit fields can have white; lets the user know what can be changed.  (C) Use an extra label field to explain form usage.